# How do you update an attribute with a button from a join table with another controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, routes, model, controller

I have a rails application, where I have set up a scaffold named event, users with devise and compared them in a third table `UserEventStates`, which makes it possible for each user to select their state for each event different (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038157/how-can-users-have-a-different-status-for-each-event-without-duplicating-in-rail)). In my `events_controller`, I have a create action which sets the status for each user to 0 (default). I can display and count the states as expected, but how can I update them through a button and how can I change the `.update(state: 1)` to `.update(state: state)` and set/specify the state in my view? I tried the following:

**Edit: I found out that the error is based on the route `get /update_user_event_state/:id`, it should be another.. How do I find out which route I need?**

```
#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
   before_action :set_event, only: %i[ show edit update destroy update_user_event_state]
   before_action :set_user_event_state, only: %i[ show update_user_event_state]

   def create
      @event = Event.new(event_params)
      @users = User.all 

      respond_to do |format|
         if @event.save
            format.html { redirect_to event_url(@event), notice: "Termin wurde erstellt" }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
            @users.each do |user|
               UserEventState.new(user_id: user.id, event_id: @event.id, state: 0).save
            end
         else
             format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
             format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
      end
   end

   def update_user_event_state
      self.update(state: 1)
   end

   private
      def set_event
         @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      end

      def set_user_event_state
         @ues_event = UserEventState.where(event_id: @event.id)
      end

      def event_params
         params.require(:event).permit(:description, :date, :meeting_time, :start_time, :end_time)
      end
```

```rb
#app/views/events/show.html.erb
   <% @ues_event.each do |uesev| %>
      <%= uesev.user.email %>
      <%= uesev.state %>
      <%= uesev.night %>
      <%= button_to "Zusagen", update_user_event_state_path(uesev) %>
   <% end %>
```

```
#config/routes.rb
   devise_for :users
   resources :events do
      resources :users
   end
    
   get '/update_user_event_state/:id', to: 'events#update_user_event_state', as: 'update_user_event_state'
      
   root "events#index"
```

Comment: At the very least you need to use a form wrapped around email, state and so on, instead of just button_to

Answer (score -1):

`get '/update_user_event_state/:id', to: 'events#update_user_event_state', as: 'update_user_event_state'`

Change the above routes to have 2 parameters.

1. First parameter will have the event id
2. Second parameter will have state value(I believe its an id)

`get '/update_user_event_state/:id/:state_id', to: 'events#update_user_event_state', as: 'update_user_event_state'`

Now in the views add an extra parameter for the user which would pass the state_id parameter to the controller while clicking the button.

```
#app/views/events/show.html.erb
   <% @ues_event.each do |uesev| %>
      <%= uesev.user.email %>
      <%= uesev.state %>
      <%= uesev.night %>
      <%= button_to "Zusagen", update_user_event_state_path(uesev, state_id: YOUR_STATE_ID_VALUE) %>
   <% end %>
```

Now access this state_id parameter in the controller on `update_user_event_state` method like below

```
   def update_user_event_state
      self.update(state: params[:state_id])
   end
```

Posted this answer assuming that the existing state updation workflow works perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't allow the user to select a new state

Comment: Oops my bad,...  Now he needs a dropdown option in the `show.html.erb` page. Whenever someone selects a state in dropdown, then it should send a request to `/update_user_event_state/:id/:state_id` path via ajax.